# VSCODE no Ubuntu com erro de unknown word

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Estou usando VSCODE com Ubuntu e após copiar um programa (python) que está funcionando em ambiente VSCODE com Windows ele apresenta em várias linhas algumas palavras com erro "Unknown word" isso acontece até mesmo em linhas de comentários (vide imagem abaixo).

Estou usando o Python 3.6 e já tentei alterar a versão do python mas o erro continua.

Alguma sugestão...?
Obrigado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso é apenas uma configuração para correção de erros de digitação. Deve estar configurado para utilizar o dicionário em inglês e, assim, acusando erro em todas as palavras em português.

Comment: já tentou instalar algum lint ou intellisense de python? Normalmente o sublinhado azul é para Info e não para error(vermelho) ou warning (amarelo)

Comment: Obrigado. não tinha percebido que era isso.